# Convert image data frame into pandas data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, image

I have images (jpg archives) with dataframes (think that I have screenshots of an excel spreadsheet) and I want to transform it to a pandas data frame.

Does anyone has a suggestion of how could I accomplish this

Thanks

I am thinking in using something like OCR, but I do not know how could I implement this in python

Answer (score 2):

You may consider **pytesseract**, OCR library in python, to help you extract those data out from your JPG archives.

Note that there has many OCR library that can be implemented in python, however, i recommend you to try out pytesseract first since it can activate something called **Page Segmentation Mode (PSM)** in order to improve your ocr accuracy by specify how to treat an image provided. Here is a code sample :

```
# code sample of implementing OCR with page segmentation mode (psm) config
target = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='--psm 10')
```

To implement it in python, you may follow this medium blog [Image Table to DataFrame using Python OCR](https://medium.com/@lidores98/image-table-to-dataframe-using-python-ocr-773c8afb713d) which will explain you step-by-step to transform your image data (in this case, your jpg archives) into dataframe. I think that is the one that you are looking for. However, **for the page segmentation mode option, you must choose one that suited with your data format by yourselves**. You can take a look for detailed of each psm options at [Tesseract Page Segmentation Modes (PSMs) Explained: How to Improve Your OCR Accuracy](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/15/tesseract-page-segmentation-modes-psms-explained-how-to-improve-your-ocr-accuracy/)

**To maximize the performance of OCR**, it is important to note that image processing techniques should be applied to enhance the image quality before performing OCR. Simple libraries such as Pillow or OpenCV can be used for this purpose. It is preferable to extract data from a sharp image rather than a blurred one, as this can significantly improve OCR accuracy. Therefore, it is crucial to consider image enhancement as a priority. It should be noted that the quality of data has a direct impact on OCR performance, so **the better the data quality, the higher the OCR accuracy will be.**

Good luck !